# Query to find Root Task for each Task in Snowflake?

Tags: dependencies, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task, root

Snowflake has a 'Task_Dependents' function which will return the root task of a single task specified.

However, I want to quickly find the root task (and therefore schedule) of about 1200 tasks in our Snowflake instance.

I suppose I can construct a for-loop process using Task_Dependents, but surely there is an easier way? SHOW TASKS does list each tasks direct predecessor. But I'm struggling to find an easy way to generate the root tasks of EVERY task -- so I know the frequency of each task.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about SHOW TASKS ROOT ONLY ?